# Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS i would like to ask that i am checking my dictionary of following in an output window like this:

```
 return [[[FBModelManager sharedModelManager] getModelDictionary:kModelListings] count];
 po [[[FBModelManager sharedModelManager] getModelDictionary] count]
```

But it is giving me an `error` like

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
```

The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
My syntax is wrong or what?

Comment: try [[[FBModelManager sharedModelManager] getModelDictionary:kModelListings] count] into one int value and the finally pass the intvalue to here **return intvalue**

Comment: i am checking count in output window what is the correct syntax ???

Comment: then error is somewhere else , put the break point and check once

Comment: check wehter result of this statement is array or not [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager] getModelDictionary:kModelListings]